# Callback interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define the exact paramters of a callback function, in my specific case for registering middleware. Middleware takes three arguments (`req`, `req` and `next`), hence my interface looks like this:

```
interface MiddlewareInterface {
  (req, res, next): void
}
```

The simplified class for it:

```
class Application {
    protected app;

    registerMiddleware(callback: MiddlewareInterface): void {
        this.app.use(callback);
    }
}
```

Sadly this is still allowed

```
registerMiddleware(() => { /* ... */ });
```

But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in javascript you can choose to ignore the arguments.

For example, let's say that I want to add a middleware that will throw if it's reached:

```
registerMiddleware((req, res, next) => {
    throw new Error("Should not have reached me!");
});
```

As the args are not used there's no need to them, this works just fine:

```
registerMiddleware(() => {
    throw new Error("Should not have reached me!");
});
```

Comment: Here's official docs saying the same thing: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#optional-parameters-in-callbacks

Comment: That's unfortunate... but well. Thanks :)